# Interpreter, if statement and let

Tags: if-statement, scheme, interpreter, let

Why is it not possible to simulate "if-then-else" construct as a function in interpreter that supports function application?
Is "let" function in Scheme similar to "if-then-else"?

Comment: You can implement `if` as a function, but if you do, you'll need to make the `then` and `else` parts functions so that you can delay their evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement in Scheme looks like:

```
(if <predicate> <consequent> <alternate>)
```

and is defined such that the `<consequent>` is *evaluated* only when the `<predicate>` is not false and such that the `<alternate>` is *evaluated* only when the `<predicate>` is false.  So you can see that something like

```
(if #t (display "okay") (shut-down-the-nsa))
```

would never actually shut down the NSA.

But, if `if` is a function, like:

```
(<operator> <operand> …)
```

then each `<operand>` is always evaluated.  In the context of an `if` statement, that means both the `<consequent>` and `<alternate>` would be evaluated - not much of an `if` then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer.
Could you please explain it about "let" function too?

Comment: @sara_123 Let is just syntactic sugar. (let ((x 2) (y 3)) (+ x y)) is the same as ((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 2 3) though it's not necessarily implemented that way in the interpreter.